# ¿Cómo comparar campos de una consulta MSSQL con múltiples condiciones?

Tags: sql, mssql

un saludo.
Tengo una duda con SQL, como verán tengo registros donde se repite el campo de RFC y el campo de fechasPrimeraPublicación, lo que deseo hacer es quedarme solamente con un registro de cada RFC, estos registros tienen que pasar por múltiples condiciones al campo de SUPUESTO.

```
RFC          |SUPUESTO      |fechasPrimeraPublicacion|
-------------|--------------|------------------------|
AASG610312FZ7|CANCELADOS    |              2019-10-01|
AASG610312FZ7|FIRMES        |              2019-10-01|
AATA820319FD4|CANCELADOS    |              2019-10-01|
AATA820319FD4|FIRMES        |              2019-10-01|
AGR0607075E3 |CONDONADOS    |              2019-07-01|
AGR0607075E3 |FIRMES        |              2019-07-01|
BPR040709FJ3 |CANCELADOS    |              2017-05-01|
BPR040709FJ3 |NO LOCALIZADOS|              2017-05-01|
```

Por ejemplo, en este caso si el SUPUESTO es CANCELADOS y FIRMES también, entonces deja el registro que tiene CANCELADOS

```
RFC          |SUPUESTO      |fechasPrimeraPublicacion|
-------------|--------------|------------------------|
AASG610312FZ7|CANCELADOS    |              2019-10-01|
AASG610312FZ7|FIRMES        |              2019-10-01|
```

Otro ejemplo, en este caso si el SUPUESTO es CONDONADOS y FIRMES, entonces deja el registro de CONDONADOS.

```
RFC          |SUPUESTO      |fechasPrimeraPublicacion|
AGR0607075E3 |CONDONADOS    |              2019-07-01|
AGR0607075E3 |FIRMES        |              2019-07-01|
```

Estos ejemplos están pensados cuando solamente hay dos registros, pero puede que haya tres o 4 registros con mismo RFC, fechasPrimeraPublicacion pero diferente SUPUESTO. Pero las condiciones siempre tienen que hacerse de 2 en 2, porque ya tengo un algoritmo que elige el supuesto decidiendo de 2 en 2 registros.
Si pudieran ayudarme estaría agradecido.

Comment: ¿Podrías llegar a tener los cuatro supuestos para un mismo RFC? en ese caso que es lo que buscas ¿mostrara dos? ¿mostrar solo uno?